# Deleting photos

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photo-stream

When I try to delete my photos from my iphone to get more storage space (which I have run out of) it says that they will delete every where. I don't want then to be deleted from my iPad as my iPad syncs with my iPhone. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete from your "My Photo Stream" you will get this warning. The Photo Stream is automatically synced across all devices using your Apple ID. If you delete from one, it will delete from all that sync to that stream.

If you switch to Albums and select Camera Roll, you will be deleting photos from your iPhones storage only.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to iTunes, select your iPhone in the sidebar, import all photos.
Once all photos are imported, you'll be presented with a dialog box that will allow you to delete all the camera roll photos.
Then you'll need to use iTunes to sync the photos you want.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way I've found to bulk delete photos off an iPhone, is the following:

1. In Photos, click on the button at the top left until you get to "Years"
2. For each year click on the strip of photos. Important don't click on the title
3. For each collection click on the strip of photos. Again, don't click on the title
4. Now press select. Then for each Moment press select.
5. When you've selected every moment, press the Trash icon.

This still requires deleting every moment, but at least it is faster than deleting every individual photo.