# Delete videos on OS X

Tags: macos, photos, data-synchronization

I have videos taken with Photo on my iPhone

How do I delete them on OS X

I followed this question [Deleting photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93503/deleting-photos)

Imported to Photos.app, highlight them all and chose delete. I then get a prompt saying they will be deleted from all my devices and confirmed. They are deleted from my Mac but they come back every time I attach my iPhone again i.e. they are not deleted from the device even though OS X says they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant section from the manual: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21294?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Summary: you can delete photos/videos through Photos/iCloud (https://icloud.com), but they are not removed immediately. They are moved into a **Recently Deleted** album (like the Trash on your Mac) and deleted automatically later. (They are kept for 40 days so it tales a long time for them to disappear)

Note in Photos.app this is not a normal album but accessible by File->Show Recently Deleted.

You can open the **Recently Deleted** album and delete the videos/photos from there to remove them from the device permanently. Make sure that you have a backup, because you can not undo this operation.

Comment: So recently deleted is now empty on the Mac - but I still have videos on the iPhone and they show up as import

Comment: Do you have "iCloud Photo Library" on your phone turned on?
( https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204264 )